# Deploying Kubernetes on bare metal rather than VM

Tags: kubernetes

Stupid question, but right now I'm deploying my Kubernetes cluster inside a VM. Is there a way to deploy it directly onto my machine?

I'm sure there has to be a easy fix but many of the docs I've read have been focused on deploying it inside VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using some flavor of Linux; otherwise the information below won't be useful to you.

The easiest way of *bare metal* deployment ("onto your machine") is by using [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/). The documentation for that is excellent.

(If you need help with then reply with your exact OS flavor and version and I can edit this answer to reflect that specific situation.)